# How do i Validate old password while updating user password?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

What's the proper way to validate old user password while updating new password?
So far i have tried and always get error: **Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client**

What i did:
I tried using bcrypt to compare the old password from req.body with user existing password and then hash with bcrypt before saving. Comparing the password using bcrypt gave the error above. Not comparing the old password at all and just saving new password works properly.

My code:

```js
exports.updatePassword = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { oldPassword, password } = req.body;

    let updatedPassword = {
      password: password,
    };

    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.userId },
      { $set: updatedPassword },
      { new: true, useFindAndModify: false }
    );
    // validate old password
    bcrypt.compare(oldPassword, user.password, function (err, match) {
      if (!match || err)
        return res.status(400).send('Please enter correct old password');
    });
    //hash password and save user
    bcrypt.genSalt(12, function (err, salt) {
      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        user.password = hash;
        user.save();
        return res.json({user});
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).send('Something went wrong. Try again');
  }
};
```

Comment: This particular error is telling you the server has already responded to the client request and should have stopped executing. But is still executing and wants to send another response but at this point, the client is not listening anymore.  You might consider having a proper if-else condition.

Comment: `bcrypt.compare` is asynchronous. `await` it (as a promise) instead of passing a callback, or put the stuff that should run *after* the comparison, and especially after your `if (!match || err)` statement, *inside* that callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `updatePassword` function is ending before you actually process everything. To avoid nested function calls and returns, use the `async` methods provided by [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) (also check their recomendation on using async vs sync).

Regarding the code itself, you are updating the user's password before checking if the password is valid. You should get the user from the db, check if the current password matches, and only then insert the new hashed password into the db.

```js
exports.updatePassword = async (req, res) => {
  const { oldPassword, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // get user
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).send('User not found');
    }

    // validate old password
    const isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compare(oldPassword, user.password);
    if (!isValidPassword) {
        return res.status(400).send('Please enter correct old password');
    }

    // hash new password
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

    // update user's password
    user.password = hashedPassword;
    const updatedUser = await user.save();

    return res.json({ user: updatedUser });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send('Something went wrong. Try again');
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much this worked. would like to point out a minor mistake.  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 12) is hashing the existing user password, so should be const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

Comment: @Babadinho Nice! I've edited the code to fix the password variable